# How to set any font size for nodes in a "global" mindmap

Tags: fonts, fontsize, mindmaps

I did not find an issue that would attempt to define a setting for the font size (including any font size) here at tex.stackexchange.com. There is a probability that I am posting an issue that will become "duplicate", but I will post anyway. My question is how to set any font size for the nodes of a mindmap in a "global" way. Although it is a simple matter, I think there are some subtleties in it.

[image: Here my example]

Here my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{anyfontsize}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[paperwidth=5cm,paperheight=5cm]{geometry}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap}
\begin{document}
\centering\begin{tikzpicture}[mindmap]
    \tikzstyle{every node}=[text width=1cm,align=flush center,minimum size=1cm]
         \node [concept, text=white] at (0,0) 
      {any other text}
    child [concept color=blue!50, grow=0,level distance=80]
    {node [concept] (text) {Text}}; 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here my own answer, using `\fontselect{X-size-unitdimen}{X-size-unitdimen}\selectfont`. I consider that to have effect it is necessary to use `\selectfont`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{anyfontsize}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[paperwidth=5cm,paperheight=5cm]{geometry}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap}
\begin{document}
\centering\begin{tikzpicture}[mindmap]
    \tikzstyle{every node}=[font=\fontsize{2mm}{3mm}\selectfont,text width=1cm,align=flush center,minimum size=1cm]
         \node [concept, text=white] at (0,0) 
      {any other text}
    child [concept color=blue!50, grow=0,level distance=80]
    {node [concept] (text) {Text}}; 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: My figure while own answer]

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to compile with `lualatex` and use OpenType fonts (not the old TeX Type 1 fonts), you can get any size and spacing you like, even non-integer values. With a package such as `textpos` you can place the text anywhere, but I will not code that here. MWE:

```
\documentclass{article} % Default font size. Process with lualatex.
\usepackage{fontspec}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\normalsize{\@setfontsize\normalsize{11.43pt}{15.824pt}}
\normalsize
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
Hello World.\\
Hello World\\
Hello World\par
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\normalsize{\@setfontsize\normalsize{13.723bp}{17.448bp}}
\normalsize
\makeatother
Hello Again\\
Hello Again\\
Hello Again\par
\end{document}
\\\
Compile that with `lualatex` and look at the resulting PDF.
```